# Displaying last modified date/time for webpages

Tags: search, last-modified

Is it possible to let google search return the last modified date/time for each webpage by adding something to the url parameter after `www.google.com/search?q=...`? Or, is there a simple way to get such information?

**Additional question**: Why does google not include such information in the search results? It is very essential information, and does not seem to require additional job provided that google crawls thourgh each page.

Comment: By adding `&tbs=qdr:h` you can limit the results to the last hour. You can also use d for day, w for week and y for year.

Comment: The above still works as of 7/22/14. "m" for month seems to work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or, is there a simple way to get such information?

Try [`netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) (or `telnet`, any other simple networking tool).

Command:

```
$ nc stackoverflow.com 80
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[...]
Last-Modified: Sat, 07 Jan 2012 14:01:34 GMT
```

Answer (score 1):

As far I know that is gerneral not possible exept you embed in your html code a hint when it was generated while google read your site.

In that case you can find the date in the sourcecode of the cached file in the google cache.